# Ошибка KeyError: 3 при установке библиотеки cairo

Tags: python, cairo

Не могу установить библиотеку cairo.

код:

```
C:\Users\spz>python -m pipwin install cairocffi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\pipwin\__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .command import main
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\pipwin\command.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import pipwin, __version__
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 13, in <module>
    import js2py
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\js2py\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from .base import PyJsException
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\js2py\base.py", line 2965, in <module>
    @Js
     ^^
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\js2py\base.py", line 165, in Js
    return PyJsFunction(val, FunctionPrototype)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\js2py\base.py", line 1377, in __init__
    cand = fix_js_args(func)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\js2py\utils\injector.py", line 27, in fix_js_args
    code = append_arguments(six.get_function_code(func), ('this', 'arguments'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\spz\Desktop\Py\Lib\site-packages\js2py\utils\injector.py", line 121, in append_arguments
    arg = name_translations[inst.arg]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 3
```

Перепробовал эти команды:
python -m pipwin install cairocffi - выдает ошибку KeyError:3

pip install pipwin

pipwin install cairocffi

pip install pycairo

Переустановка библиотек не помогает, перезагрузка компьютера тоже. GPK установить нет возможности.
Python 3.12.0.
Что можно сделать, чтобы установить конкретно эту библиотеку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую откатить питон до версии 3.11. Обычно это помогает. Дело в том, что Python 3.12 вышел недавно и библиотеки еще не успели обновиться до него.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Откатил до версии 3.10.10 и всё получилось! Благодарю за подсказку!

Comment: @ВиталийПетров, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте поставить галочку.